# Why does my app crash instead of passing error from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm learning node.js and I'm looking for errors in my code that causes it to crash instead of passing them

```
const db = client.db(dbName);
db.collection(cName).aggregate([
                {
                   query
                }
            ]).toArray((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    callBack(err);
                } else {
                    callBack(null, result);
                }
            });
```

For instance when I don't pass dbName/CollectionName the app crashes and requires me to restart

MongoError:

> collection names cannot be empty,
>
> database name must be a string

Please advise.

Comment: Your code shows no `callback` argument to actually call.  Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like error is occurring before coming to callback. Add your code in `try catch` block.

Try this:

```
try {
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  db.collection(cName).aggregate([
    {
      query
    }
  ]).toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      callBack(err);
    } else {
      callBack(null, result);
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```